# Is it better to add a conditional inside or outside of a for loop for cleaner code?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, design-patterns

So this may sound simple, but I have a method that has a for loop inside, inside the forloop the method createprints needs a map of "parameters" which it gets from getParameters, now there are 2 types of reports, one has a general set of parameters and another has that general set and a set of its own.

I have two options:

Either have 2 getparameters method, one that is general and another that is for rp2 but also calls the general parameters method. If I do this then it would make sense to add the conditional before the for loop like this :

```
    theMethod(){

        if (rp1){
            for loop{
                createPrints(getgenParameters())
                do general forloop stuff 
           }
        }else{
              for loop{
                createPrints(getParameters())
                do general forloop stuff
                }
        }
    }
```

This way it only checks once which parameters method to call instead of having the if statement inside the loop so that it checks every iteration (this is bad because the report type will never change throughout the loop) but then this way, repeating the for loop looks ugly and not clean at all, is there a cleaner way to design this?

The other option is to pass in a boolean to the get parameters method and basically you check inside which type of report it is and based on that you create the map, this however adds a conditional at each iteration as well.

From a performance perspective, it makes sense to have the conditional outside the loop so that its not redundantly checked at each iteration,  but it doesnt look clean, and my boss really cares about how clean code looks, he didnt like me using an if else code block instead of doing it with ternary operators since ternary only uses one line (i think performance is still the same no?).

**Forgot to mention I am using java, i cannot assign functions to variables or use callbacks**
Inside the method, there was an if else code block before the for loop something like

```
String aVariable;

if(condition){
aVariable= value1;
}else{
aVariable =value2;
}
```

so i initially wanted to just create a boolean variable like isreport1 and inside if/else code block also assign the value cause it was using the same condition. And then as mentioned before pass in the parameter but, my boss again said not use booleans in parameters, so is this case the same I shouldnt do it here?

Comment: You forgot `if`(I presume).

Comment: Ternaries aren't *necessarily* more efficient than `if...else` and they tend to obfuscate the code. If you're code is ultimately printing something (`createPrints()`) it's unlikely that this is going to be your bottleneck, anyway. The answer to "which is faster?" is *always* profile it and see.

Comment: sorry the code wasnt what i meant, i dont usually use pseudocode, fixed it now

Comment: Yes i didnt really think ternaries were faster which is why I am confused, he said it looks cleaner which i find highly opinionated, but thats not my concern for this question, should i add the conditional logic inside of ONE general loop or have it like i have shown above, which is running less steps because its only one conditional rather than in each iteration but it also doesnt look clean, is there a way I can make it look cleaner? I was also told not to pass in a boolean to a method because the only way you can use it is an if else and so its not really good practice.

Comment: Regarding the performance of doing the `if` inside the loop on every iteration, despite the condition not changing during the loop: this depends. In languages compiled to machine code (either at compile-time, or at runtime with a JIT), the CPU will do branch prediction and figure out that the same branch is selected every time, so the performance impact will probably be negligible. In languages that are interpreted, the overhead is likely to be larger because the CPU is predicting branching in the interpreter rather than in your code directly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction

Comment: Another option worth considering is that you could have an `if` statement (or ternary expression) *before* the loop to select either `func = getgenParameters` or `func = getParameters` and then write one loop calling `func()` unconditionally. If you can't assign a function to a variable directly in your language, you could use polymorphism to achieve the same result.

Comment: I am using java, does that have branch prediction as you mentioned? Also I cant assign functions to variables in java i dont think so. How would i implement polymorphism in this case in java, i am not sure how it would apply in this case.

Comment: There's branch prediction and you can (but this time should not) assign *method literals* to variable. See my answer.

Comment: Java is compiled to machine code at runtime by the JIT, so yes, you should benefit from branch prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch prediction is a property of the CPU, not of the compiler. All modern CPUs have it, don't worry.

Most compilers can pull a constant condition out of the loop, so don't worry again. Java does it, too. Details: The `javac` compiler does not do it, it's job is to transform source cod to byte code and nothing else. But at runtime, the time-critical parts of the byte code get compiled in the machine and there many optimizations happen.

> Forgot to mention I am using java, i cannot assign functions to variables or use callbacks.

You sort of can. It's implemented via anonymous classes and since Java 8, there are lambdas. Surely worth learning, but not relevant to your case.

I'd simply go for

```
       for loop{
            createPrints(rp1 ? getgenParameters() : getParameters())
            do general forloop stuff 
       }
```

as it's the shortest and cleanest way for doing it.

There are tons of alternatives like defining `Parameters getSomeParameters(boolean rp1)`, which you can create easily using "extract method" from the above ternary.

> From a performance perspective, it makes sense to have the conditional outside the loop so that its not redundantly checked at each iteration, but it doesn't look clean, and my boss really cares about how clean code looks

From a performance perspective, it all doesn't matter. The compiler is damn smart and knows tons of optimizations. Just write clean code with short methods, so it can do its job properly.

> he didnt like me using an if else code block instead of doing it with ternary operators since ternary only uses one line

A simple ternary one-liner makes the code much easier to understand, so you should go for it (complicated ternaries may be hard to grasp, but that's not the case here).

> (i think performance is still the same no?).

Definitely. Note that

- most program parts are irrelevant for the performance (Pareto principle)
- low level optimizations rarely matter (the compiler knows them better)
- clean code using proper data structures matters

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I did not actually know about branch prediction, it’s funny they didn’t teach us that in the data structures and algorithms class so I was simply thinking about the number of steps. But yeah I guess for me the concern right now is what constitutes clean code. I actually did do it how you did it at first but I wasn’t sure if that’s clean, ie using a ternary to pick which method to use. And I had 3 variables that were assigned in an if else but I was told to use ternaries for them. I had thought it was best to only have one conditional and use it for all 3

Comment: When you say complicated ternaries do you mean like where there’s multiple else ifs or what constitutes as a complicated ternary such that I should resort to a regular if else block

Comment: @xeu I'd bet, they didn't teach you about multiscalar architectures, register renaming, precise exceptions, cache coherency protocols and tons of other features of modern CPUs either. We get all of this for free and it simply works.... most programmers have never heard about it and they don't need it. `+++` Clean code - that's highly subjective, but think about two things: Is it easy to change? Is it easy to understand (imagine a new programmer knowing the language rather well but not knowing your code).

Comment: @xeu Complicated ternary - that's subjective, too. For me, something like `a ? b : c ? d : e` is on the edge. Whenever any expression gets long and multi-line, extracting local variables and/or methods should be considered.

Comment: Well that’s the thing, it is subjective. Like it makes more sense to me to have one if/else code block and if all the assignments depend on the same condition I do all the assigning there with the variables initialised beforehand rather than create 3 separate ternary operators just cause they are technically one line each.

Comment: In this case I’m an intern so as long my logic is right I’ll go along with the code review as long as it’s not very obviously bad

Answer (score 1):

Most "debates" about whether one way of writing some chunk of code is more efficient than another are missing the point.

The JIT compiler performs a lot of optimizations on your code behinds the scenes.  It (or more precisely the people who wrote it) know a lot more about how to optimize than you do.  And they will have the advantage of having done extensive benchmarking and (machine level) code walk-throughs and the like to figure out the best way to optimize.

The compiler can also optimize more reliably than a human can.  And its developers are constantly improving it.

And the compiler does not need to be paid a salary to optimize code.  Yes.  Every hour you expend on optimizing is time that you could be spending on something else.

So the best strategy for you when optimizing is as follows:

1. First get the code implemented.  Time spent on optimizing while coding is probably wasted.  That is classic "premature optimization" behavior.  Your intuition is probably not good enough to make the right call at this stage.  (Few people are genuinely smart enough ...)
2. Next get the code working and passing its tests.  Optimizing buggy code is missing the point.
3. Set some realistic, quantifiable goals for performance.  ("As fast as possible" is neither realistic or quantifiable).  Your code just needs to be fast enough to meet the business requirements.  If it is already fast enough, then you are wasting developer time by optimizing it further.
4. Create a realistic benchmark so that you can *measure* your application's performance.  If you can't (or don't) measure, you won't know if you have met your goals, or if a particular attempted optimization has improved things.
5. Use profiling to determine which parts of your code are worth the effort optimizing.  Profiling tells you the hotspots where most of the time is spent.  Focus there ... not on stuff that is only executed occasionally.  This is where the 80-20 rule comes in.

I would talk to my boss about this.  If the boss is not on board with the idea of being methodical and scientific about performance / optimization, then don't fight it.  Just do what the boss says.  (But when be willing to push back if you are blamed for missed deadlines that are due to time wasted on unnecessary optimization.)

There are two kinds of efficiency in Software Engineering:

- The efficiency of the program
- The efficiency of the programmer

These two efficiencies are in conflict.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense in terms of performance. I didn’t really think this part I am working on will make a big difference on performance anyways, this is after the implementation was done and I was told to kind of join methods together and write more clean code which I am now realising may be more about readability or number of lines in cases like these? What do you think I should look for and what constitutes “clean code”

Comment: Clean code is a matter of opinion.  I think you should ask the person who is telling to clean up you code to give you some pointers.  (It would be a bad idea to spend a lot of time rewriting code if you don't understand what your boss really wants.  Ask.)  Also, look at https://x-team.com/blog/principles-clean-code/ for some ideas

Comment: Yeah I realised that, and I have asked him quite a few questions but as you mentioned a lot of time shouldn't be spent on things like this and i dont think it will look good to keep asking or discussing simple design questions. You mentioned the compiler will do most of the optimization and we shouldn't focus on that too much but shouldn't we code as if the compiler will not optimize the code? Like does adding a conditional inside of a loop in this case with the compiler optimization out perform adding it outside of the for loop? Is it good practice to depend on the compiler to do the work?

Comment: Also sometimes the opinion of clean code to my boss sounds like an issue of optimization to me. For instance is it true that its best to not pass in a boolean as a parameter in a method? For example I have a locale parameter that is needed for a sql query to generate rpt2 in said locale language, while rp1 doesnt require the locale in the query. I wanted to pass in the locale boolean in the function and check first if its rp2 before doing the query, he told me to instead call the query to get the labels in the language before the method that generates BOTH reports, thats an extra query if rp1.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
theMethod(getParametersCallback){

        for loop {
            createPrints(getgenParametersCallback)
            do general forloop stuff 
       }
}

. . .  . .

if (rp1){
    theMethod(getgenParameters)
}
else {
    theMethod(getParameters)
}
```

Comment: i am using java, i dont think there are callbacks like this?

Comment: @xue.  There are a variety of ways to implement callbacks in Java.  For example, lambdas or anonymous classes can both be used for this.

Comment: @xeu well, #java wasnt present. And there is no doubt, java has callbacks.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-synchronous-callbacks-java/

Comment: Sure, but using callbacks for something simple like this i feel is not simplifying the code

Comment: @xeu "simplifying the code" is a broad subject. You do things in some context. for example, you might just have a class `class Printer { Printer (IParamProvider pp, IPrintCreator pc) {} TheMethod () { pc.Print(pp); } }`. How simple huh? Now we speaking of dependency injection and other object oriented concepts